# Calculating Fragmentation offset doubt

Tags: ipv4, ip, fragmentation

Suppose we have a data of 4500 bytes which passes through 2 routers of MTU 2600 and 1400 respectively. What will be the resulting fragments at the 2nd router (1400 MTU one)?

The 4 fragments at 2nd router will be

`<1380,20>` `<1196,20>` `<1380,20>` `<544,20>`

Here each pair is  `<IP data, IP header size>` and MTU size is `1400`.

We have to make all fragment sizes as multiple of eight and not necessarily the last one.

Now do we remove the 4 bits from the first fragment and add it to 2nd fragment immediately and make it <1200,20> or do we keep on removing 4 bits from each of the fragments and add it to the last fragment making the second fragment as <1192,20>?

Which one is correct?

Also, I don't understand when to pad bits and when to remove bits to make it a multiple of eight.

By default, should we try to pad bits first or remove bits first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:**

Since you completely changed the question (very bad form), I will attempt to answer the new question.

You are still very confused about how fragmentation works. With an original payload of `4500` octets passing through a router to a network with an MTU of `2600` you would get:

1. `20` octet IPv4 header and `2576` octet payload
2. `20` octet IPv4 header and `1924` octet payload

When those fragments pass through another router to a network with an MTU of `1400`, you would get:

1. `20` octet IPv4 header and `1376` octet payload
2. `20` octet IPv4 header and `1200` octet payload
3. `20` octet IPv4 header and `1376` octet payload
4. `20` octet IPv4 header and `548` octet payload

As I wrote before, you *do not* move anything between fragments, nor do you add any padding.

A fragment on a network with an MTU of `1400` cannot have a payload of `1380` octets because that is not divisible by eight. The largest fragment could be `1376` octets.

---

**Original:**

You seem to be very confused about fragmentation. Your packet will not end up with fragments the way you have depicted.

If, in your example, those are four separate packets, then they all meet the MTU of `1400`, and no fragmentation will occur.

Assuming all the data bytes you have for the four fragments were originally a packet with a `4451` octet payload, and the MTU is `1400`, it would be fragmented into four packets at a router where the MTU drops to `1400`:

1. `20` octet IPv4 header and `1376` octet payload
2. `20` octet IPv4 header and `1376` octet payload
3. `20` octet IPv4 header and `1376` octet payload
4. `20` octet IPv4 header and `323` octet payload

You do not move octets from one fragment to another, nor do you add any padding.

[*RFC 791, Internet Protocol*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791) has a complete description and example of fragmentation:

> Fragmentation
>
> Fragmentation of an internet datagram is necessary when it originates
> in a local net that allows a large packet size and must traverse a
> local net that limits packets to a smaller size to reach its
> destination.
>
> An internet datagram can be marked "don't fragment."  Any internet
> datagram so marked is not to be internet fragmented under any
> circumstances.  If internet datagram marked don't fragment cannot be
> delivered to its destination without fragmenting it, it is to be
> discarded instead.
>
> Fragmentation, transmission and reassembly across a local network
> which is invisible to the internet protocol module is called intranet
> fragmentation and may be used [6].
>
> The internet fragmentation and reassembly procedure needs to be able
> to break a datagram into an almost arbitrary number of pieces that can
> be later reassembled.  The receiver of the fragments uses the
> identification field to ensure that fragments of different datagrams
> are not mixed.  The fragment offset field tells the receiver the
> position of a fragment in the original datagram.  The fragment offset
> and length determine the portion of the original datagram covered by
> this fragment.  The more-fragments flag indicates (by being reset) the
> last fragment.  These fields provide sufficient information to
> reassemble datagrams.
>
> The identification field is used to distinguish the fragments of one
> datagram from those of another.  The originating protocol module of an
> internet datagram sets the identification field to a value that must
> be unique for that source-destination pair and protocol for the time
> the datagram will be active in the internet system.  The originating
> protocol module of a complete datagram sets the more-fragments flag to
> zero and the fragment offset to zero.
>
> To fragment a long internet datagram, an internet protocol module (for
> example, in a gateway), creates two new internet datagrams and copies
> the contents of the internet header fields from the long datagram into
> both new internet headers.  The data of the long datagram is divided
> into two portions on a 8 octet (64 bit) boundary (the second portion
> might not be an integral multiple of 8 octets, but the first must be).
> Call the number of 8 octet blocks in the first portion NFB (for Number
> of Fragment Blocks).  The first portion of the data is placed in the
> first new internet datagram, and the total length field is set to the
> length of the first datagram.  The more-fragments flag is set to one.
> The second portion of the data is placed in the second new internet
> datagram, and the total length field is set to the length of the
> second datagram.  The more-fragments flag carries the same value as
> the long datagram.  The fragment offset field of the second new
> internet datagram is set to the value of that field in the long
> datagram plus NFB.
>
> This procedure can be generalized for an n-way split, rather than the
> two-way split described.
>
> To assemble the fragments of an internet datagram, an internet
> protocol module (for example at a destination host) combines internet
> datagrams that all have the same value for the four fields:
> identification, source, destination, and protocol.  The combination is
> done by placing the data portion of each fragment in the relative
> position indicated by the fragment offset in that fragment's internet
> header.  The first fragment will have the fragment offset zero, and
> the last fragment will have the more-fragments flag reset to zero.

The reason that the fragments must be divisible by eight is that the fragment offset field (`13` bits) is three bits smaller than the total length field (`16` bits). That means to have an offset large enough, you must account for those three bits (`2^3=8`). By requiring each fragment to be a multiple of eight, then the offset (multiplied by eight) can be as large as the total length.

Comment: Actually the entire question was different and I only wrote a part of question previously. Please check my edited question.

Comment: Again, those would not be valid fragments.

Comment: When we fragment at the first router it will be <2580,20> and <1920,20> at first and afterwards after adjusting it, it will be <2576,20> and <1924,20> . Now <2576,20> will be fragmented at 1400 MTU router as <1380,20> and <1196,20> . Here 1380 + 1196= 2576. This was my thought. By 2600 MTU, I meant it also included 20 bit IP header, so actual data it could hold is only 2580 and 2580 + 20=2600 is MTU

Comment: Yous fragments don't have payloads divisible by eight. `1380` is not divisible by eight. On a `1400` octet MTU, the largest payload can be `1376` for a fragment.

Comment: Just a comment about saying the header is 20 octets.  Certainly almost all packets have a header length of 20, but MTU is defined as the maximum for the total length including the header.  It might be longer than 20, and might be different lengths on different fragments because some options eg record route only go on first fragment.

Comment: @RonMaupin That was exactly my doubt. Whether to remove 4 bits from first fragment and put it in second fragment as <1376,20> and <1200,20> or remove 4 bits from both fragments like <1376,20> and <1192,20> and total of these 8 bits removed is put at the last fragment (the 4th one). Because in both representations, the first two fragments have data which is multiple of 8.

Comment: You are not doing anything with bits. You are not moving anything. You fragment on an eight-octet (64-bit) boundary. There is no moving or padding of anything.

Comment: @RonMaupin Maybe I was not clear before but 1380 is not a multiple of 8 right ? Also, 1196 is not a multiple of 8.

Comment: The last fragment doesn't need to be evenly divisible by eight. I have no idea why you are concentrating on bits. The eight is octets (bytes or eight bits). You do not move or pad anything (bits or octets).

Comment: @RonMaupin Hmm <1196,20> is not the last fragment. We have more two fragments behind it as shown in the question.

Comment: I have no idea where you get that fragment. It is not a valid fragment, and it would never exist in your example. That is my point, what you have simply is wrong. Look at the edit to my answer, and it will explain how to fragment, and then fragment again.

Comment: @Zephyr, your premise of "_The 4 fragments at 2nd router will be <1380,20> <1196,20> <1380,20> <544,20>_" is incorrect. It would never be that.

Comment: @RonMaupin Ok, one last question. <1376,20> , <1192,20> , <1376,20>, <556,20> from <1380,20>, <1196,20>,<1380,20> and <544,20> . Why is above sequence of fragmentation incorrect. Just tell me that and everything will be clear.

Comment: The packet with a payload of `2576` octets will first be fragmented to a packet with a payload of `1376` octets (the largest you can have on an MTU of `1400`). That leaves a payload of `1200` octets (`2576-1376=1200`), which fits into a second fragment without further fragmentation, so the original packet with a `2576` octet payload would be fragmented into the two packets with payloads of `1376` and `1200`. The router treats (routes, fragments, etc.) packets individually, without regard to what came before, and it doesn't even expect anything to come after.

Comment: @Zephyr, if I understand your thinking, you seem to think that the second router is still treating the two fragments it receives as part of the same packet, but to the second router, those are two completely separate packets, each needing to be fragmented individually. Routers are to route packets as fast as possible, and they do not relate any received packet to any other received packet, which would take time and resources that is better spent on routing faster. Routers do not reassemble or realign fragments; that is up to the destination host.

Answer (score 3):

I don't disagree for a second with the description in previous answer, but as I assumed the 4500 packet was the whole length -- as that is what is compared to the MTU -- my arithmetic gives different answers for the final fragments B2 and C4 below.

Assuming 20-byte headers throughout, a 2600-byte MTU will make maximum packets of 2596-bytes and a 1400-byte MTU will make maximum packets of 1396.

```
    Packet A1: 4500 = (20 + 4480)
    Fragmented through MTU = 2600 will give
    Packet B1: 2596 = (20 + 2576)
    Packet B2: 1924 = (20 + 1904)

    B1 fragments through MTU 1400 into
    Packet C1: 1396 = (20 + 1376)
    Packet C2: 1220 = (20 + 1200)

    B2 fragments through MTU 1400 into
    Packet C3: 1396 = (20 + 1376)
    Packet C4:  548 = (20 + 528)
```

Kind regards,

Jonathan

Comment: <1376,20>, <1192,20> , <1376,20>, <556,20> from <1380,20>, <1196,20>,<1380,20> and <544,20> . Why is above sequence of fragmentation incorrect. Just tell me that and everything will be clear. Why are you removing 4 from first fragment (1380-4) and adding it to second fragment and not last fragment(4th one).

Comment: When second router receives packet B1 its length 2596 is greater than MTU 1400.  So it fragments it.  It doesn't buffer and wait for any possible successive fragments.  That's the job of the recipient.  You can't have fragments of payload length 1380 it's not a multiple of 8. The fragment is thus 20 + 1376 = 1396.  Packet C2 gets the remainder because it fits.  Packet B2 might not yet exist if router 1 is slow.

Comment: ... and indeed, depending on router 1, packet B2 might have been routed a different way to a completely different router.  Our router 2 with MTU 1400 might never see it. Hence it *must* deal with packet B2 on its own.

Comment: I think where we differ is that you are assuming the entire original packet is `4500` octets, but the question actually says, "_Suppose we have a data of 4500 bytes..._" I believe that means the payload (data) of the packet is `4500` octets.

Comment: @Zephyr there is nothing removed from the first fragment because it would never be fragmented as `1380`. It will be fragmented as `1376` to start with. You do not remove or add anything when fragmenting. A packet fragment is a packet itself, and packets are processed individually. When B1 (`2576`) is received, it is fragmented to the largest possible fragment (`1376`). What is left over simply fits into another packet without need for fragmentation. Nothing is added subtracted, shifted, or padded.

Comment: @RonMaupin -- absolutely: including/excluding header explains difference in arithmetic.  I think I assumed packet length rather than payload length because that's what's compared to MTU.

Comment: @RonMaupin So we always try to add the left over bits to the "next adjacent fragment" right ? If it's not possible then we keep on going till the last fragment until we find a appropriate adjacent fragment to add the left over bits on.

Comment: Packet C2 leaves router 2 before packet B2 has finished arriving.